# Breaking change Grails 2.2.0 -> Grails 2.3.5 with XmlSlurper / GPathResult and selecting attirbutes with unknown namespaces

Tags: grails, groovy

Given the following XML:

```
<Response xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Exception>
        <Code>01</Code>
        <Message i:nil="true" />
    </Exception>
    <Details />
</Response>
```

In grails 2.2.0 I had code like the following that allowed me to query the value of the /Response/Exception/Message/@i:nil attribute without knowing the namespace 'i' of the attribute:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(<xml text>)
assert xml.Exception.Message.@nil.text() == 'true'
```

However after upgrading to grails 2.3.5 `xml.Exception.Message.@nil.text()` now returns an empty string.

I'll note that using the namespace in the attribute selector like `@i:nil` does indeed work, however my basic problem is that I am dealing with an API that is unpredictable about the namespace prefix it uses or whether it even uses one at all.

I tried constructing the `XmlSlurper` so that it is namespace un-aware like `new XmlSlurper(false,false)` but doing that I am unable to select the attribute in any way (neither `@nil` nor `@i:nil` works).

Does anyone know how I can solve this breaking change?

Comment: You might have better luck using an non-validating XmlParser. I can post a sample of how to create one if you like.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore thanks for the suggestions, but that would be a last resort since the project being upgraded uses `XmlSlurper` / `GPathResult` extensively (i.e. it would be a lot of work to migrate to using `XmlParser`, the issue I present here recurs throughout the entire project).

Comment: i know it does not work (at least with groovy 2.3.9), but I would expect '@*:nil' to be the syntax, that _should_ work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dmahapatro and @cfrick on their help towards this answer. I can only conclude that there is indeed a regression in the version of Groovy that comes with Grails 2.3.5. My final solution is a not-so-painful workaround that gives behavior similar to the earlier version of Groovy that came with Grails 2.2.0.

The following is a mixin method I use to augment `GPathResult` instances:

```
/**
 * Workaround GPathResult regression that doesn't play nice with attribute namespace prefixes
 * @param self the parent node
 * @param key the attribute name, WITHOUT namespace-prefix (multiple attribute names with different namespace prefixes not supported).
 * @return a GPathResult Attribute implementation corresponding to the key argument
 */
static GPathResult attr(GPathResult self, String key) {
    if(self instanceof NodeChildren)
        self = self[0]

    if(self instanceof NodeChild) {
        def kvp = self.attributes().find {
            it.key ==~ /.*[:\}]?${key}$/
        }
        new Attribute(kvp?.key ?: '', kvp?.value ?: '', self, '', [:])
    } else {
        new Attribute('', '', self, '', [:])
    }
}
```

The implementation supports XML attributes with or without namespace prefixes, and `XmlSlurper`s constructed with or without being namespace aware. It accepts any `GPathResult` and returns a non-null `Attribute` `GPathResult` sub-class. This allows us to use syntax like follows (see the example in the question):

```
assert xml.Exception.Message.attr('nil').text() == 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

This way it would work using either `XmlSlurper` or `XmlParser`.

```
def xmlSlurp = new XmlSlurper( false, false ).parse( xml )

assert xmlSlurp.'**'.find {it.name() == 'Message'}?.attributes()?.findResult{k,v ->   
    k.endsWith( 'nil' ) ? v : null 
} == 'true'
```

You can also use no-arg constructor for `XmlSlurper`.

UPDATE:
A cleaner approach would be

```
xmlSlurp.Exception.Message[0].attributes().find { it.key.endsWith( 'nil' ) }?.value
```

if we know `Message` will always be present

Comment: Hard to swallow but thanks. `xml.Exception.Message[0].attributes().find { key, value -> key.endsWith('nil') }?.value` works similarly.

Comment: i'd rather go with something like `find{ it.key ==~ /(.*:)?nil/ }` in case there are multiple attributes ending with the same fragement.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, and I do not understand how to implement the above solution. So I just kept playing with the code until I got it to work.... Here is what I did

```
    def validating = true,
    namespaceAware = true,
    allowDocTypeDeclaration = true
    return new XmlSlurper(validating, namespaceAware, allowDocTypeDeclaration).parse(url)
```

Comment: Please consider posting a new question here stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.